# AngularJS $http - IE11 issues with POST calls using Restangular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, restangular

I'm using Restangular to interface with REST services in my AngularJS project and some POST calls seem to get skipped on IE11 alone (possibly IE10 too, but I haven't checked). The strange thing is that, everything works fine when the Developer Options tab is open, so am unable to inspect the behaviour. But, I placed alerts and they execute until the line before the actual call.

```
alert("Executes till here");
resource.post($scope.value).then(function(newResource){
                alert("No response!");
        })
    }
```

I thought it might be a caching problem and set it to 'false' as below, but that doesn't help either.

Restangular.setDefaultHttpFields({'cache':'false'});

Has anybody else faced a similar issue?

Comment: IE strikes again! can only rec: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie